# Array of object transform

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of objects like this:

```
[
  { week: 1, day: 1, todo: "eq1" },
  { week: 1, day: 3, todo: "eq2" },
  { week: 4, day: 6, todo: "eq3" },
  { week: 4, day: 7, todo: "eq4" },
]
```

I would like to transform to sth like this:

```
[ 
   1: {
       1: { todo: "eq1" },
       3: { todo: "eq2" }
   },
   4: {
       6: { todo: "eq3" },
       7: { todo: "eq4" }
   }
]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an array for the todo list, because you may have more than one item in the list to do.

```js
var data = [{ week: 1, day: 1, todo: "eq1" }, { week: 1, day: 3, todo: "eq2" }, { week: 4, day: 6, todo: "eq3" }, { week: 4, day: 7, todo: "eq4" }],
    object = function (data) {
        var r = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            r[a.week] = r[a.week] || {};
            r[a.week][a.day] = r[a.week][a.day] || [];
            r[a.week][a.day].push({ todo: a.todo });
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Solution as asked (*it overwrites same week and day todos!*):

```js
var data = [{ week: 1, day: 1, todo: "eq1" }, { week: 1, day: 3, todo: "eq2" }, { week: 4, day: 6, todo: "eq3" }, { week: 4, day: 7, todo: "eq4" }],
    object = function (data) {
        var r = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            r[a.week] = r[a.week] || {};
            r[a.week][a.day] = { todo: a.todo };
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I ended up with the same pattern, sorry for that, didn't check attentively enough :) +1

Answer (score 0):

@Sergey was partial correct. You will not achieve same output as you are storing in array and other values will be set to `null`. Also you should use `Object` instead.

**Note** *This is just a sample code for demo purpose and hence I have just checked resultObj's availability*

```js
var data = [
  { week: 1, day: 1, todo: "eq1" },
  { week: 1, day: 3, todo: "eq2" },
  { week: 4, day: 6, todo: "eq3" },
  { week: 4, day: 7, todo: "eq4" },
];

var resultObj = {};
var resultArr = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!resultObj[item.week]){
    resultObj[item.week] = {};
    resultArr[item.week] = {};
    }

  if(!resultObj[item.week][item.day]){
    resultObj[item.week][item.day] = {"todo": item.todo}
    resultArr[item.week][item.day] = {"todo": item.todo}
  }
});

document.write("Object:<br/> <pre>" + JSON.stringify(resultObj, 0,4) + "</pre>");
document.write("Array: <br/> <pre>" + JSON.stringify(resultArr, 0,4) + "</pre>");
```